# Python expression with trailing comma: syntax error or tuple?

Tags: python, syntax, tuples

Python assignment statement with extra comma at end creates a tuple (not syntax error):

```
>>> tuple_int = 3 ,
>>> tuple_int
(3,)
>>> another_one = 4,
>>> another_one
(4,)
>>>
```

Why?

Caused a hard-to-find bug for me.

The python syntax does not seem to allow this:  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html

I'm using python 3.4.1 on windows.

Comment: Yes, because it is the comma that defines a tuple, not the parentheses.

Comment: The comma is not part of a statement, it is part of an *expression*, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists